# Do I need a special web host to be able to utilize a PHP framework like CakePHP or Symfony?

Tags: php, frameworks, web-hosting

Do I need a special feature on a web host to be able to utilize a PHP framework like CakePHP or Symfony?

If so, what feature am I looking for?

If not, are they hard to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to ask yourself some questions;

- **Do you really need to use Framework?**
  If you are working on a small project, working it with such frameworks will just make your web pages work slower than they normally would. They have too many features which you might not need and eventually those features which you don't even use will use resources.
- **Do you really want to go through all user guide?**
  Don't forget even for the simple query you want to make, you have to read the user guide. Security measures, queries, URLs, forms, templates etc.. etc.. You might want to save yourself sometime but eventually you would have to spare some time first to learn how to use them.

If you want to use framework, use it for bigger projects. This might save you time (considering you don't have all the features they offer in your library). Make sure Framework you are going to use can do better than you can.

Generally their requirements will match many hosts. Asking for extra requirements to run, will decrease their popularity.

I never used framework, instead I coded my own but I took a look at [**CodeIgniter**](http://codeigniter.com/). If you want to use framework, I wouldn't suggest to use CakePHP. I heard it is using too much memory. I believe [**CodeIgniter**](http://codeigniter.com/) is rising star.

To answer your other question;
 They are easy to install. Each of them might be different, you have to read user guide but it is not like extract it, put it in a folder and they are ready to run. You have to first configure them (you might need to configure some folders, paths etc).

Answer (score 4):

No you dont, and they are quite easy to install. However you would need to have some knowledge of how to use those MVCs.

Comment: Thanks, so is it as simple as just dropping in a folder of php files?

Comment: yes it is. But do make sure that the hosting does support php in the first place. I hope you knew that already.

Comment: sorry, i meant no disrespect. but hey you are better than me, when I started I did not even know what php was. Good luck.

Comment: You will quite often need to do some configuration - not just a simple case of dropping in the files - but this is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to choose web host for Framework, make sure you watch the PHP Version including its extention and configuration except your webhost is VPS class or above.

Iw will be wise if you consult to webhost you choose about which framework will you install.

Most of framework i know, all is really to install. especially if it has good documentation.

if you still not sure what Framework you will use, it will be better if you choose framework with good documentation.